# Flutter Firebase Batch Update Unhandled Exception: Bad state: This batch has already been committed and can no longer be changed

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart

i am trying to use a for loop to update documents in my cloud firebase using batch and then commit, but my code keeps giving me an error that This batch has already been committed and can no longer be changed, it doesn't even update my document even once

My code

```
    WriteBatch batch = FirebaseFirestore.instance.batch();
//Create a batch
print(cart_numbers.toString());
Future update() async {
    for (var i = 0; i < cart_numbers.length; i++) {
        print('is iterator wooooooorking !!!!!' + i.toString());
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("items")
            .doc(cart_numbers[i].toString()).get().then((value) {
                print('==============================================' +
                    value.data().toString());
                print('==============================================' +
                    value.data()['quantity'].toString());
                int newer = value.data()['quantity'];
                newer--;
                print('newwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwerrrrrrrrrrrrr' + newer.toString());
                batch.update(
                    //Give the ref of document.
                    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('items')
                    .doc(cart_numbers[i].toString()),
                    //And the data to add in it.
                    {
                        'quantity': newer
                    }
                );
            });
    }

}

void start() async {
    await update();
    batch.commit();
}

start();
```

Comment: Would you like to edit the question to format your code so that it's easier to read?

Comment: sorry, i just formatted the code, can you help?